Can you translate this from Proto-Celtic?
The following excerpt from a modern novel is written in Proto-Celtic. Decipher it.
Windeto Enderos rextums anwissoms katowom wirom onkus swexs blēdanyābos aiwestī. Bonnejetor bināti nāmantam talamoni ɸariwid gniyonti mīlā ed.
Tetēgee Enderos dū kolanei Stilsonī ɸlārei bibekʷe astnūs esyo tregete esyo.

An important observation:

 "Enderos" and "Stilsoni" are capitalized despite not being the first words of the sentences they're in, so I googled Ender's Game.

So:

 Here's the full PDF of the book (from a school's site).  I searched for "Stinson", and tried to make sure to find a sentence that contains both "Stinson" and "Ender".  "Rextus" means "rule" or "law" according to this site, so there has to be a sentence with both "Ender" and "rule" or "law".  Also, "swexs" apparently means six.

I found this part:

 "Ender knew the unspoken rules of manly warfare, even though he was only six. It was forbidden to strike the opponent who lay helpless on the ground; only an animal would do that.  So Ender walked to Stilson's supine body and kicked him again, viciously, in the ribs."

